# Select only the first element from a list matching on attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to be able to select the first XML element from a set which match on attribute values.  To explain more, suppose we have the following XML:

```
<events>
    <event date="2013-06-17">
        <person first="Joe" last="Bloggs" />
        <person first="John" last="Smith" />
    </event>
    <event date="2013-01-29">
        <person first="Jane" last="Smith" />
        <person first="John" last="Smith" />
    </event>
    <event date="2012-09-03">
        <person first="Joe" last="Bloggs" />
        <person first="John" last="Doe" />
    </event>
    <event date="2012-04-05">
        <person first="Jane" last="Smith" />
        <person first="John" last="Smith" />
        <person first="John" last="Doe" />
    </event>
<event>
```

I want to select a unique set of person element matching on the first and last attributes, i.e. the result set would look like this:

```
<person first="Joe" last="Bloggs" />
<person first="John" last="Doe" />
<person first="Jane" last="Smith" />
<person first="John" last="Smith" />
```

There are a number of solutions all of which are variations on this theme:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//person">
    <xsl:if test="not( preceding::person[ @first = current()/@first and @last = current()/@last ] )">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, it seems to me that I should be able to include the test from the `xsl:if` as a predicate on the select from the `xsl:for-each`, e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//person[ not( preceding::person[ @first = current()/@first and @last = current()/@last ] ) ]" />
```

Of course, though, the `current()` function won't like this, but I'm just wondering if anyone knows how this could be done in a single XPath statement?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 or XSTL 1.0? In XSLT 2.0, you could use the **xsl:for-each-group** element. In XSLT 1.0 you would use a technique known as Muenchian Grouping.

Comment: I can use XSL 2.0, but, though the for-each-group works a little neater than what I'm currently doing, it does not address the issue: how to state the selection as a single XPath statement that could be used, for instance, in an apply-templates call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 approach using `for-each-group` with `group-by`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="events">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="event/person" group-by="concat(@first, '|', @last)">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms

```
<events>
    <event date="2013-06-17">
        <person first="Joe" last="Bloggs" />
        <person first="John" last="Smith" />
    </event>
    <event date="2013-01-29">
        <person first="Jane" last="Smith" />
        <person first="John" last="Smith" />
    </event>
    <event date="2012-09-03">
        <person first="Joe" last="Bloggs" />
        <person first="John" last="Doe" />
    </event>
    <event date="2012-04-05">
        <person first="Jane" last="Smith" />
        <person first="John" last="Smith" />
        <person first="John" last="Doe" />
    </event>
</events>
```

into

```
<person first="Joe" last="Bloggs"/>
<person first="John" last="Smith"/>
<person first="Jane" last="Smith"/>
<person first="John" last="Doe"/>
```

With XSLT 1.0 you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="by-name" match="event/person" use="concat(@first, '|', @last)"/>

<xsl:template match="events">
  <xsl:for-each select="event/person[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-name', concat(@first, '|', @last))[1])]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml for an explanation.

The Muenchian grouping could be simplified to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="by-name" match="event/person" use="concat(@first, '|', @last)"/>

<xsl:template match="events">
  <xsl:copy-of select="event/person[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-name', concat(@first, '|', @last))[1])]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course instead of copying to the result tree you could as well do an `apply-templates` and transform the first item in each group that way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="by-name" match="event/person" use="concat(@first, '|', @last)"/>

<xsl:template match="events">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="event/person[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-name', concat(@first, '|', @last))[1])]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person">
  <foo>...</foo>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 2.0 and `for-each-group` you would need to use a variable storing the items e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="events">
  <xsl:variable name="first-person-in-groups" as="element(person)*">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="event/person" group-by="concat(@first, '|', @last)">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-person-in-groups"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person">
  <foo>...</foo>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that way you have a sequence of `person` elements you can `apply-templates` on.

Comment: This answer has the same structure as the solution I've already adopted, albeit a bit neater, but doesn't address the actual question I asked: can this be done as a _single_ XPath statement and, if so, how?  I'd guess from this though, the answer is that it cannot be done.

Comment: My XSLT 1.0 solutuion is a rewrite of the XSLT 2.0 (where you need the `for-each-group`) but I will show you how in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 with the key defined you can use a single expression to filter out the first in each group.

Comment: @rumplestiltzkin, I have edited the answer to show how to `apply-templates` on a node-set respectively sequence of unique `person` items. It is a combination of XSLT and XPath however, not a single XPath expression.

Comment: Suite!  I had tried using the Muenchian grouping approach, but I couldn't get it work for elements and attributes, only atomic data.  Clearly I didn't search far enough.